# Net Beans IDE cant launch my local host

Tags: html, css, netbeans

[image]

Hi guys ,I just started using NetBeans IDE, I could launch localhost initially but after editing the html and adding the css ,I cannot launch localhost anymore.Any ideas how to debug it.

Comment: There is a screenshot of my ide included.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `<link>` tag outside the `<head>` tag.

Please move the `<link>` tag inside `<head>` tag like below,

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />  <!-- fix -->
  </head>
    <body>
       .....
       code
       .....
    </body>
</html>
```